# make a new columns based on row-wise data in r

Tags: r, dataframe

This is minimum reproducible example, but my real data is really huge so I cannot do it manually

```
id<-1:4
mathpass_1<-c("pass","fail","pass","fail")
mathpass_2<-c("fail","fail","fail","fail")
mathpass_3<-c("fail","fail","pass","pass")
mathpass_4<-c("fail","fail","pass","fail")

math<-data.frame(id,mathpass_1,mathpass_2,mathpass_3,mathpass_4)
```

so, the data is like this

```
> math
  id mathpass_1 mathpass_2 mathpass_3 mathpass_4
1  1       pass       fail       fail       fail
2  2       fail       fail       fail       fail
3  3       pass       fail       pass       pass
4  4       fail       fail       pass       fail
```

the Id is student's Id.
I want to make an additional column ( binary variable)
if a student get at least one pass, they will have "pass"
and if a student did not get any pass, they will have "fail"

so, I want to make a column "pass" like this,
but I made it manually.

```
id<-1:4
mathpass_1<-c("pass","fail","pass","fail")
mathpass_2<-c("fail","fail","fail","fail")
mathpass_3<-c("fail","fail","pass","pass")
mathpass_4<-c("fail","fail","pass","fail")
pass<-c("pass","fail","pass","pass")
math<-data.frame(id,mathpass_1,mathpass_2,mathpass_3,mathpass_4,pass)
```

```
> math
  id mathpass_1 mathpass_2 mathpass_3 mathpass_4 pass
1  1       pass       fail       fail       fail pass
2  2       fail       fail       fail       fail fail
3  3       pass       fail       pass       pass pass
4  4       fail       fail       pass       fail pass
```

However, my real data is really huge that I cannot do manually.
How can I do this with code? (non-manual way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ifelse(rowSums(math[,-1]=="pass")>0,"pass","fail")`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
math %>%
  mutate(pass = ifelse(rowSums(across(is.character, ~.x == "pass")) >0, "pass", "fail"))

  id mathpass_1 mathpass_2 mathpass_3 mathpass_4 pass
1  1       pass       fail       fail       fail pass
2  2       fail       fail       fail       fail fail
3  3       pass       fail       pass       pass pass
4  4       fail       fail       pass       fail pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
id<-1:4
mathpass_1<-c("pass","fail","pass","fail")
mathpass_2<-c("fail","fail","fail","fail")
mathpass_3<-c("fail","fail","pass","pass")
mathpass_4<-c("fail","fail","pass","fail")
pass<-c("pass","fail","pass","pass")
df<-data.frame(id,mathpass_1,mathpass_2,mathpass_3,mathpass_4,pass)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(res = max(c_across(starts_with("mathpass_"))))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 7
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      id mathpass_1 mathpass_2 mathpass_3 mathpass_4 pass  res  
#>   <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 pass       fail       fail       fail       pass  pass 
#> 2     2 fail       fail       fail       fail       fail  fail 
#> 3     3 pass       fail       pass       pass       pass  pass 
#> 4     4 fail       fail       pass       fail       pass  pass
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, in `base R`:

```r
math$pass <- apply(math, 1, \(x) if (any(x[-1] == "pass")) "pass" else "fail")
math

#>   id mathpass_1 mathpass_2 mathpass_3 mathpass_4 pass
#> 1  1       pass       fail       fail       fail pass
#> 2  2       fail       fail       fail       fail fail
#> 3  3       pass       fail       pass       pass pass
#> 4  4       fail       fail       pass       fail pass
```