# filter() function in r with negative index

Tags: r, filter

I am making minimum reproducible example, but my data is really huge
so I should use negative index for filter() function

```
id<-1:4
breakfast<-c("pass","fail","pass","fail")
lunch<-c("fail","fail","fail","fail")
dinner<-c("fail","fail","pass","pass")
sweets<-c("fail","fail","pass","fail")
blah1 <- 1:4
blah2 <- 1:4

dataframe<-data.frame(id,breakfast,lunch,dinner,sweets,blah1, blah2)
```

I want to see if any person who successfully eat "breakfast" or "lunch"
so, it seems like I can do it with the following code below,
but this is only for this minimum dataset

```
  dataframe %>%
    dplyr::filter(breakfast=="pass"|lunch=="pass")
```

because my dataset is really huge, I should use different strategy.
I should use a minus index such as

```
dataframe %>%
filter( daframe[,c(-1,-4,-5,-6)]=="pass")
```

but it seems to not work.

Comment: This is almost identical to your previous question, the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Please provide the output you expect from your test data and explain why answers to your [previous, almost identical, question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72555644/make-a-new-columns-based-on-row-wise-data-in-r) do not meet your needs.

Comment: Becuase the previous question's answers are trowing an error...

Comment: Try `dataframe %>% filter(if_any(!c(1, 4, 5, 6), ~ . == "pass"))`